# Подсчет сокращенных ссылок

Tags: c#

Есть у меня задача, суть которой в том, что на вход программы подаю урл, получаю сокращенный урл, при этом урлы хранятся в базе. И нужен подсчет переходов по ссылке. Чтобы сделать сокращенную ссылку буду использовать функцию GUID, для каждой ссылки получаю guid, этот же гуид и саму ссылку помещаю в базу, guid это ключевое поле. Далее беру этот GUID и например обрезаю его получаю произвольную короткую ссылку. типа http://url.com/guid Сам вопрос, как мне реализовать момент подсчета ссылки, вот я отдал другому пользователю эту ссылку он по ней перешел и как мне посчитать количество переходов и сам механизм как сам переход сработает. Что использовать лучше для построения такой программы, я имею ввиду или wсf, или ASP. Подобного много, но мне нужна своя реализация. Подскажите алгоритмически.

Comment: А в чем затруднение? Когда `url.com` получает запрос на `/guid`, он добавляет 1 к счетчику для этого `guid`, и возвращает редирект на соответствующий URL.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ , а я как раз и не совсем понимаю как организовать этот редирект.

Comment: Берете из базы URL, возвращаете его клиенту с кодом HTTP 308 (ну или 301).

Comment: А по стеку технологий легче это все реализовать на чем?

Comment: Не знаю, по-моему, на чем угодно, логика же элементарная